# Replace first occurrence of . in hive

Tags: hive, hql

I want to find the first dot (`.`) in the string of a column and replace it with text.

Tried `Regexp_replace`, but couldn't find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hive> select regexp_replace ('Hello ... World ...','^(.*?)\\.','$1{text}'); 

Hello {text}.. World ...
```

Comment: There suppose to be a `V` symbol left to the answer